# Extracting only a certain amount of rows from a large table

Tags: ssis, etl, pervasive-sql

I have a legacy system on a pervasive (btrieve) database that has a table that lists stock on hand for products. The table has > 5,000,000 rows, but only 115,000 of the rows have a value other than 0. Those are the rows that I am trying to extract into an MSSQL database.

Now, normally I would put an index on the qty column and interrogate the table by saying `where qty <> 0`, however, the quantities are in 15 separate columns (size1_stock, size2_stock etc).

In selecting the whole table (as a linked server in MSSQL with an insert into clause), it takes about 2.5 hours. I need to dramatically reduce the time taken to do this.

There is no other predicate for my query that I need to add in except where the sum of all those columns <> 0.

Options:

- Take all 5,000,000 rows (takes about 2.5 hours- not feasible)
- Add a predicate such as `where size1_stock + size2_stock .. <> 0` (not really any quicker)
- Add an index on all 15 columns (would this work?? it would take way too long to create the index I believe, although perhaps it could be done before migration day)

Unfortunately, purging the table is not an option- the vendor says those records need to stay.

Any advice would be great!

Comment: how long does the query with predicate of size1_stock+...<>0 takes to run on the source database (pervasive (btrieve)), as if this is fast, what we can do create a temp/staging table in source system pervasive (btrieve) and insert these valid records from big table into this table and then select * from this temp/staging table via MSSQL linked server.

Comment: Thanks- I hadn't actually thought of this simply method. I'kk guve ut a try tomorrow and see how it goes.

Comment: You need to work out where the performance issue it: finding the small amount of rows in the table? Copying the data over the network? Inserting into your target table. If you break this up you might be able to tune each piece, i..e use a tool to select the limited data into a local flat file - how long does that take? Copy the file to your SQL Server - how long does that take? Insert the file into your target table - how long does that take? extended operations over linked servers aren't always reliable.